# Can the @Id and @DocumentId Annotations Be Specified on Different Fields?

Tags: hibernate-search

I see the **@Id** and **@DocumentId** annotations in the code examples of the [Hibernate Search Reference Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.5/reference/en-US/html_single/) always appear together on the same field, such as follows.

```
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @DocumentId
    private Integer id;

    //...
}
```

I want to know whether it is possible to use the **@Id** and **@DocumentId** annotations on different fields, such as follows?

```
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @DocumentId
    private Integer isbn;

    //...
}
```

The purpose of this requirement might be using the **@Id** annotation for performing **Hibernate** queries, and using the **@DocumentId** annotation for performing **Hibernate Search** queries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the answer is yes, you can do it. We even have a unit test just for that.

Next question is: would I recommend it?

Not really. Keep the @DocumentId on your @Id and add a @Field on your isbn field. IMHO, it's far more intuitive and it will allow you to search on the isbn. There's no good reason for you to rely on such a corner case.

Comment: Thanks, Guillaume, for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Technically the *@DocumentId* is optional, it will default to use the same field as *@Id*. I guess we should remove it from some examples to clarify that we generally don't expect you to use it.

So the *@DocumentId* exists specifically to allow you to override the default choice.

Comment: Thanks, Sanne, for the explanation. Now I know the \@DocumentId will override the \@Id.